# Disable camera capture button?

Tags: security, camera

I have one app in which i am using barcode scanner, so i can't completely disable the camera. but i don't want camera to capture photos. I want camera in read only mode.

> Basically i want to restrict user from taking photos.

So is there any way to achieve this.
My device is rooted, so i can i modify the code of system's camera or is there any OS level setting or any app available.

Any Helpwill be appreciated! ThankYou!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using an app locker, e.g. [Smart AppLock (App Protector)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.smartlockfree). Photos are taken by the camera app, regardless of whether you invoke it from the app drawer, a shortcut, widget, or via pressing the camera button. So if you lock the camera app (and the playstore app, so the user doesn't simply install an alternative camera app -- also make sure to disable [unknown-sources](/questions/tagged/unknown-sources) and lock the settings app), only somebody knowing the password/pattern you've set up to protect those apps can use them.

**Explanation:** While blocking access to the camera app, this does not affect the barcode scanner. The barcode scanner for sure accesses the camera *hardware*, but not the camera *app:* the latter would not know *what* it aquires (just that it focusses on "something", but it's not recognizing what this "something" is and so would not know whether it aquired a barcode correctly). You can also verify this by checking the permissions the barcode app asks for: its permission list will for sure include `Hardware controls: Take pictures and videos`, which means it accesses the hardware *directly.* For accessing it via another app (e.g. the camera), it would not need this permission but rather call that app via an "intent" (see: [what is intent in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578051/what-is-intent-in-android)), so that called app would do the intended action.

Comment: I can not lock the camera app, beacause i want my other user to use my App which itself uses 'Barcde scanner' app, So if i lock my camera then user can't even use that app also.

Comment: Does the barcode scanner app invoke the camera app? I never heard that. Have you tried?

Comment: oh great! I think problem solved.. The barcode scanner app doesn't access the system camera.. So i can lock my system camera.

Comment: Well, it accesses the camera *hardware* for sure, but not the camera *app*. Simply take a look at the barcode scanner app's permissions: it wouldn't need the camera permission if it would call the camera app via an intent instead. Also, how should the camera app know whether it successfully aquired a *barcode*? It has not the necessary features for that :) So: Glad your issue has been solved!

Comment: You are GREAT!!!

Comment: I updated my answer to include the explanation (with even some more details :).